# hacker rank compiler shows error when string length function input is modified

Tags: python, string

My code produces satisfied result in **hacker rank** compiler window for eleven out of fifteen test input in a certain problem. However, when i make subtle change in my code, all the the test inputs are run as OK.

This is a snippet of my previous code which shows error (terminated due to timeout).

```
for ind, letter in enumerate(string):
    if letter in vowels:
        kevin += len(string[ind:])
    else:
        stuart += len(string[ind:])
```

When i changed the above code as below all inputs are run successfully.

```
for ind, letter in enumerate(string):
    if letter in vowels:
        kevin += len(string) - ind
    else:
        stuart += len(string) - ind
```

Aren't these two codes equivalent?

Comment: `ind` is an integer correct? I really don't know what you're trying to do here.

Comment: enumerate function gives the first value as integer i think.

Comment: hacker rank the minion game problem.

Comment: probably failing due to time, creating strings is expensive

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You probably want to be more careful. Your question first reads like you want to know about a real "compiler error". But in essence, you are asking about the differences of two code snippets that do the same, but not exactly the same ;-)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, terminated due to timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These code snippets are entirely equivalent apart from two things:

1. Second one is more optimized - There are no multiple subset creations of `string`.
2. Second one works for any [collection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Collection) - can work on dict, list, tuple, string and anything that implements both `__len__` and `__iter__`.

---

As you've added the error, saying it's a timeout error, I'm leaning towards issue #1 which is the string creation.

If you're creating a subset of a very long string you do the following operations for each iteration:

1. Allocate n-1 bytes of space. (*Slowish*)
2. Set all that space to zero (done internally, probably using `calloc()`)
3. Copy n-1 bytes from the original string to that new space. (*Slow*)
4. Find out the length (*A very fast operation*)
5. Deallocate the space. (*Fast as well*)

For long strings, this whole sequence can be a heavy operation, especially done for every iteration.

Second algortithm does this:

1. Get length (*fast operation*)
2. Substract integer (*fast operation*)
3. ???
4. Profit.

Comment: indeed, adding `assert len(string) - ind == len(string[ind:])` demonstrates the equivalence.